# Rails 4 - country select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, country-codes

I am making an app with Rails 4.

I use gem 'country_select' for a country list.

The last question in this form is a select field to pick a country.

The list populates fine. However when I press submit on the form, I keep getting an error that says Country can't be blank.

I have a validation in my address model:

```
validates_presence_of :street_number, :street, :zip, :country
```

But I can't see what's wrong with the form to make the select function not pick a country.

```
            <%= simple_form_for(@address) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :unit %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :street_number %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :street %>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :building %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :city %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :region %>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :zip %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :country, priority: [ "Australia", "New Zealand", "United Kingdom" ] %>
                    </div>
```

So -taking the suggestion below from MarsAtomic, my hash shows that a country selection is in the create hash:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
authenticity_token: Jax0qIsyVj2V5CeK01ee79Ctmmmm7nqob8FRwS7KDIgGnRaNDR8A==
address: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  unit: ''
  street_number: '23'
  street: asdf
  building: ''
  city: asdf
  region: pdf
  zip: '2000'
  country: NZ
  main_address: '0'
  project_offsite: '0'
commit: Create Address
controller: addresses
action: create
```

My controller has this create method:

```
def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)
    authorize @address


    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @address }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

THANKS! I'M A NUMPTY. I misspelled country int he strong params in the controller. Sorry everyone. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dump your params hash and see whether country data is being passed.

Comment: Put the following code at the bottom of every single one of your views:<div class = "debug" >
    <%= yield %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>

Comment: hi - I pasted the output above. A country choice is included, but the form error says the field can't be blank

Comment: Can we see your create method in the controller?

Comment: Is country permitted on strong parameters call in your controller?

Comment: Are you sure you're using country_select correctly? IIRC, country_select has a special form element, so` <%= f.input :country,` should be something like`<%= country_select_tag :country,`